# Concentrating on Breathing

Tags: vajrayana

I have been experiencing energy flow on my head,especially at the tempels,  even after meditation. I have only started on Breathing concentration. What is it? I have stopped meditation for fear of something wrong might have happened. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Buddhism SE. We also have a [*Help Center*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) with useful resources that you might like. Enjoy your time here.

Comment: Are you sure it's not hyperventilation (breathing too much)?

Answer (score 3):

According to my experience in meditation, first time it was happened to me. Do not fear to do the mediation.

These are the steps for Anapana-sathi meditation.

1.Concentrate your mind into breathing process.

2.In that time,try to think about only breathing patterns.

After you do it more times you feel relax in your mind.
It gives you to easily concentrate for your work.

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know the technique you had been practising...and the problem you are facing might be related to the way you practise too...but, in general, the mind has fallen into the habit pattern of wandering around here and there. And hence once you start trying to concentrate your mind it is natural for the mind to resist and this resistance is felt on the body in the form of unpleasant sensations...So, I would request you to continue the practice for at least 7-8 days for 10-15 minutes and see if the problem persists...Here is an excellent video by Ven Goenka on '[Mindfulness of Breath/Anapana Meditation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5CJLKTn47k)'. It is also necessary that you start in small chunks of 15-20 minutes. Life on the path of liberation is like training for marathon...you start with warm up and then keep on adding to it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been experiencing energy flow on my head,especially at the tempels, even after meditation. I have only started on Breathing concentration. What is it?

Nothing to worry about. Some people experience such phenomena when concentration increases. Its just a sign (nimitta) that concentration is being strengthened.

If you practice Samatha meditation, then just return attention to the breath at the abdomen or the entrance of the nostrils.

If you practice Vipassana meditation, then just note the sensation a couple of times and return attention to the abdomen.

Do the same if fear arises.

Try not to get caught up in sensations or the interpretation of them. That removes focus from the practice. I would also recommend finding a good teacher that can help you on the Path.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, your mind is concentrating in the wrong way, causing stress to your temples & brain.

Buddhism does not teach to concentrate on breathing. Buddhism teaches to give up craving. When you can give up craving, your mind will be quiet, silent & still. When your mind is quiet, silent & still, your mind will naturally, without any effort or intention, feel & know the breathing.

The meditation in Buddhism is called '*Mindfulness With Breathing*' rather than '*Mindfulness of Breathing*'. '*Mindfulness*' means '*to govern*' the mind & '*keep it*' free from craving.

If you practise the right way, you will get the right results.